# I.V.P. $y'=max\{1,y\}, y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Prove that

I.V.P. $y'=max\{1,y\}, y(0)=1$

have a unique solution then find this solution.

I know I should to prove

i) f(x,y) continues on R.

ii) f(x,y) bounded:

There exist M constant such that:

$|f(x,y)|\leq M$

iii) f(x,y) satisfy lipshtize condition

$|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|\leq L|y_2-y_1|$

L is lipshtize constant.

But i don't know how can I find $f(x,y)$ here

I say:

$f(x,y)=1, \ if  \ y\leq 1$

Or

$f(x,y)=y, \ if \ y>1$

But my teacher say no it's wrong answer.

I know how can i prove the three above conditions but i only want $f(x,y)$

Thanks.

Comment: I think $f(x,y)=\max (1,y)$ will be enough..

Comment: But how can i find $\partial f\over \partial y$ For this ? And how can I prove the continues

Comment: It's non-differentiable but continuous since the $\max$ of two continuous functions is continuous

Comment: Ok, what about lipshtize condition, $|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|= |\max(1,y_2)-\max(1,y_1)|$      then ?

Comment: I think we can at least study it case by case, if there's no other obvious method..

Comment: Since $y(0)=1$ and $y'\geqslant1$ it is clear that $y(x)\geqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence $y'(x)=y(x)$ and $y(x)=e^x$ for every $x\geqslant0$. Can you solve similarly the case $x<0$?

Comment: @Did For $y\leq 1$, $y'=1$ so $y=x+1$ true?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ = $$\begin{cases}
e^x \  \ \ , x\geq 0 ,\\
x+1 \ \ \ , 0<x\leq1 ;
\end{cases}$$  true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we look at the graph of the function $g: \>y\mapsto\max\{1,y\}$ then we can immediately verify that $|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|\leq |y_1-y_2|$ for all $y_1$, $y_2\in{\mathbb R}$. It follows that the function 
$f(x,y):=g(y)$ is even globally Lipschitz with respect to $y$. The standard existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs then guarantees that your IVP has exactly one solution.

If we find a solution of this IVP, e.g., through guessing, then it is **the** solution. Now at $(0,1)$ from $y'=\max\{1,y\}$ we conclude $y'(0)=1$, hence $y(x)$ will be $<1$ immediately to the left of $x=0$ and will be $>1$ immediately to the right of $x=0$. This leads to the conjecture that the solution of this IVP satisfies $y'\equiv1$ when $x<0$ and $y'=y$ when $x>0$, so that we propose as solution the function
$$y(x)=\left\{\eqalign{&1+x\qquad(x\leq0) \cr &\ \ \ e^x\qquad\ \ \ (x\geq0)\ .\cr}\right.$$A posteriori it is easily verified that this function $x\mapsto y(x)$ satisfies all the conditions.